# Imagens comprimidas com Imagick não passam no teste do PageSpeed

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Quais parâmetros posso adicionar ao `Imagick` para melhorar a compressão das imagens?

Mesmo com esse código, o `PageSpeed` do *Google* continua a acusar que as imagens precisam de redução.

```
$image = new \Imagick($request->img->path());
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$fileName = date('YmdHis') . microtime(true) . rand(111111111, 999999999) . '.' . $image->getImageFormat();
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
$image->stripImage();
$image->setSamplingFactors(array('2x2', '1x1', '1x1'));
$image->setInterlaceScheme(\Imagick::INTERLACE_JPEG);
$image->setColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$image->writeImage($path . '/' . $fileName);
$image->destroy();
```

Comment: Mas ai você tem que levar em consideração se ele esta considerando a compressão de fato ou se a foto foi reduzida com css ou com atributos como width e height, fazendo o tamanho original ser desnecessário, o que valeria (medindo o custo beneficio) gerar uma versão com tamanho melhor, resumindo "o problema pode ser parcialmente no HTML". Mas não tenho como saber sem ter detalhes, principalmente os detalhes reportados pelo pelo proprio pagespeed, pois vc pode ter interpretado mal o que eles dizem no "log"

Comment: Esse é o resultado do pagespeed onde ele aponta o problema: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-br&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infochat.com.br%2Fbusca%2Fporto-alegre%2Frs%2Ftodos%2Fjose

Comment: Caro diego, foi exatamente o que eu comentei, formulei a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A imagem original tem 628x480, ou seja a imagem fala a compactação e o "redimensionamento":

> A compactação e o redimensionamento de https://www.infochat.com.br/…1809042141221536108082.0203631465967.jpg poderiam poupar 27,9 KiB (redução de 93%).

Basta olhar na página, com o css `width: 100%` a imagem ficou com 76 de largura, ou seja você está colando com `<img>` uma imagem que é 86% maior que o necessário (não estou contando a compressão), mesmo em Desktop. O que o pagespeed-insights é criar uma imagem com o tamanho aproximado que vai usar, ou talvez mais de uma, uma com o tamanho original e outra com o tamanho reduzido.

Comment: Acabei redimensionando a imagem e funcionou, mas algumas imagens ainda precisam da compactação, teria algum outro parâmetro do imagick pra acrescentar? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-br&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infochat.com.br%2Fbusca%2Fporto-alegre%2Frs%2Ftodos%2Flemos&tab=desktop

Comment: @DiegoVieira é que o imagick assim como GD provavelmente adicionam algumas "coisinhas", aliais a compressão de 15% achei muito exagerado, o máximo que consegui com uma ferramenta que tenho própria para isto sob a sua imagem atual foi 8%, as vezes o pagespeed é meio exagerado (eu acho, pessoalmente), mas pode ser alguma camada que é independente da compressão, pode ser algo do proprio imagick.